# Tika server works fine except RTF parsing, raising invalid header (invalid OLE2) error

Tags: ajax, server, apache-tika, rft

I can parse RTF files using cURL but when I try to extract the same files with AJAX, it throws the 422 error and The tika server raises the following error:

org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: invalid header
signature; read 0x615.. Expected 0xE11… - Your file appears not to be a
valid OLE2 document

I can parse other formats such as doc, docx, xls, xlsx without any problems. Is there something wrong in calling the server via Ajax?

```
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append(file.name, file);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:9998/tika/form',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false, 
    }).done(function (data) { ....}
    }).fail(function (xhr, err) {...}
```

Comment: As I think I said yesterday on a deleted question (yours?), try doing a network-level capture of the curl post, and of yours, and compare them to see what your ajax call is doing differently with packing the file up to send

Comment: I thought there would be an error in the Ajax call, so I posted it again.